# How to write an 'optional' WHERE clause for MySQL composite primary key tables

Tags: mysql, join, composite-primary-key

I have two tables, `staff` and `staff_data`. `staff` is an ordinary table, `staff_data` is a Type/Value composite primary key table (primary key is combo of Staff_ID and Type) - so a sample of the data would look like this:

```
+----------+--------------------+----------+
| Staff_ID | Type               | Value    |
+----------+--------------------+----------+
|        1 | Department         | IT       |
|        1 | Organisation       | BigCorp  |
|      821 | Department         | Finance  |
|        1 | NetworkUsername    | smith.j  |
+----------+--------------------+----------+
```

My goal is a query that will select all staff members and their departments, **but** if they do not have a department listed in `staff_data` it will still select them but list Department as blank.

The query below only includes staff that have a Department listed in `staff_data`

```
SELECT staff.name, staff_data.Value as Department 
FROM staff JOIN staff_data USING(Staff_ID)
WHERE staff_data.Type = ‘Department’
GROUP BY staff.Name
```

But if I don’t include the WHERE clause, obviously I don’t get the data I want. How can I write a query that will list all staff, including their Department it if exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an outer join:

```
SELECT staff.name, staff_data.Value as Department
FROM staff
LEFT OUTER JOIN staff_data
    ON staff.Staff_ID = staff_data.Staff_ID
       AND staff_data.Type = "Department"
```

In a left outer join, if the right table has no values that match the constraint then the output will still contain the row from the left table.  (The columns that come from the right table will be null.)

Comment: You beat me to the punch with the `OUTER JOIN`:-(.  Don't you need `OR staff_data.staff_id is NULL` to catch the staff that don't have a department set?

Comment: @nurdglaw No. This is part of the `ON` clause, which determines which rows get joined together. Presumably he has no rows in `staff_data` with a null `staff_id`, so there would be no point to this. (Plus, it would fail the `staff.Staff_ID = staff_data.Staff_ID` test anyway.)

Comment: Thanks it works. Didn't know you could do the 'making sure Type is department' logic within the join clause.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks for the clarification - I had misread the join statement, plus I think I meant staff_type IS NULL.